# Editing Block in Concrete5

Tags: javascript, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm trying to edit a standard block in Concrete5 - the image_slider block to modify it's transition speed.

In theory this should be really simple; changing the speed value located in:

```
..concrete/blocks/image_slider/view.js
```

So I copied this file to

```
..application/blocks/image_slider/view.js
```

and changed the value.

At this point, the slider does execute the function, but for some reason the javascript is not operating as expected - its executing (I added a console.log for testing), but the slider no longer slides and the navigation arrows are missing. Inspecting the slider no class changes are happening.

I can't find any information on extending the view.js in my own application, and whatever I try doesn't seem to work.

The block I'm using can be found on their github, I'm running Concrete5 v5.7.5.2:
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/tree/5.7.5.2/web/concrete/blocks/image_slider

Comment: did you put where you said "application/image_slider/" or in the blocks folder ie: "application/blocks/image_slider/..."

Comment: @tofraser Yes I did, sorry that was my mistake. I've corrected the question.

Comment: did you try clearing the server cache? best to disable it during development.

Comment: Yes, caching has been disabled. I don't seem to trust the disabled cache...so I clear it when I encounter problems anyway.

Comment: You may trust the cache... ;-) did my answer help?

Comment: I'm not actually in front of my development machine right now, but it does look like it will solve it - I will report back once I get a moment :)

Answer (score 2):

When you're overriding a core Concrete5 block, I find it's good practice to copy over the entire blocks folder from the Concrete folder to your Application folder.

Normally this speed change can be handled in the Image Slider form, while it's being added to your page. If you're trying to update the speeds base value you're better off editing the default value passed in the image slider form during setup -> `application\blocks\image_slider\form_setup_html.php (for me it's line 298)`.

```
<?php
echo $form->number($view->field('speed'),
    $speed ? $speed : 500, 
    array(
        'min' => '1',
        'max' => '99999'
    ))?>

<span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo t('ms'); ?></span>
```

Updating '500' to your desired base speed in milliseconds should take care of it for you!

Answer (score 1):

The overriding you're doing is correct, anyway in the latest version (5.7.5.6) there is no `view.js` in `concrete/blocks/image_slider`.

So, to get it running you'll need to override the `view.php` into (`application/blocks/image_slider/view.php`).

The options are handled in the `view.php` starting at line 9:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("#ccm-image-slider-<?php echo $bID ?>").responsiveSlides({
            prevText: "",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
            nextText: "",
            <?php if($navigationType == 0) { ?>
            nav:true,
            <?php } else { ?>
            pager: true,
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($timeout) { echo "timeout: $timeout,"; } ?>
            <?php if ($speed) { echo "speed: $speed,"; } ?>
            <?php if ($pause) { echo "pause: true,"; } ?>
            <?php if ($noAnimate) { echo "auto: false,"; } ?>
            // transition
            transition: //your code here
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And, as @tofraser said, disable all caches during development.